# Generated .g file has errors

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, retrofit, flutter-dependencies

Everytime i run the `flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs` command I end up with a .g file with errors.
This is the service class I implemented myself

```
part 'NutricaoService.g.dart';

@RestApi(baseUrl: '')
abstract class NutricaoService {

  @GET('${ConfigURL.FIREBASE}/nutri/consultarPlanoNutricional')
  Future<PlanoNutricional> consultarPlanoNutricional(@Query('usuarioApp') String usuarioApp, @Query('dataConsulta') DateTime dataConsulta);
}
```

This is the function generated with retrofit in the .g file

```
  @override
  Future<PlanoNutricional> consultarPlanoNutricional(
      usuarioApp, dataConsulta) async {
    const _extra = <String, dynamic>{};
    final queryParameters = <String, dynamic>{
      r'usuarioApp': usuarioApp,
      r'dataConsulta': dataConsulta.toJson()
    };
    final _headers = <String, dynamic>{};
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    final _result = await _dio.fetch<Map<String, dynamic>>(
        _setStreamType<PlanoNutricional>(
            Options(method: 'GET', headers: _headers, extra: _extra)
                .compose(
                    _dio.options, '{FIREBASE}/nutri/consultarPlanoNutricional',
                    queryParameters: queryParameters, data: _data)
                .copyWith(baseUrl: baseUrl ?? _dio.options.baseUrl)));
    final value = PlanoNutricional.fromJson(_result.data!);
    return value;
  }
```

And this is the problem I get

```
The method 'toJson' isn't defined for the type 'DateTime'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'toJson'.
```

When I remove the .toJson() from the dataConsulta it works like a charm but I'd like that the file were already generated without the .toJson() on my query parameter DateTime dataConsulta. Appreciate it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66399567/8174223

Comment: If you don't want an ISO8061 formatted date, you can still use the same method to define `toJson` for `DateTime` and perform whatever encoding you need